# CSS Gradient Nav Design

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a nav bar just like this design

[image]

but unable to identify

1. the top right corner and bottom right corner
2. gradient color
3. shadow

what i do until now is on Code Snippet below please check and guide me on it

```css
.container {
  width: 350px;
  border: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
 }
 .left-nav {
  list-style-type: none;
 }
 .left-nav li {
  width: 250px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 0 0 10px;
 }
 .left-nav li a {
  background-color: #030406;
  line-height: 50px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  display:  block;
  border-top-left-radius: 5px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 7px 4px -4px #1c8eff;
       -moz-box-shadow: 0 7px 4px -4px #1c8eff;
      box-shadow: 0 7px 4px -4px #1c8eff;
 }
 .left-nav li a:hover {
  background-color: #000D51;
 }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <ul class="left-nav">
   <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
   <li><a href="">About Us</a></li>
   <li><a href="">Services</a></li>
   <li><a href="">FAQs</a></li>
   <li><a href="">Contact Us</a></li>
  </ul>
 </div>
```

Comment: it would be easyer if you design this using photoshop or something else and use it as an background image for your li-elements. i dont think you can't design exactly this only using css.. I would be impressed if so..^^

Comment: well the one with photoshop is too easy :), i'm trying to do it using CSS only

Comment: I'll follow this thread :D i'am curious

Comment: I currently have no access to the imgur site, so I can't see the image and what you want to achieve, but I'm pretty sure this link could help you: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_gradients.asp

Comment: the required gradient effect is a bit different from them, seems like the combination of 2 effects in gradient

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's my attempt, trying to match as close as possible.

It's all about the small details of inner gradients, shadows and borders.

```css
.container {
  width: 350px;
  border: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
  background: #0d0e0f;
  /* Permalink - use to edit and share this gradient: http://colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/#0d0e0f+0,272a2d+51,0d0e0f+100 */
  background: #0d0e0f;
  /* Old browsers */
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, #0d0e0f 0%, #272a2d 51%, #0d0e0f 100%);
  /* FF3.6-15 */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #0d0e0f 0%, #272a2d 51%, #0d0e0f 100%);
  /* Chrome10-25,Safari5.1-6 */
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #0d0e0f 0%, #272a2d 51%, #0d0e0f 100%);
  /* W3C, IE10+, FF16+, Chrome26+, Opera12+, Safari7+ */
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#0d0e0f', endColorstr='#0d0e0f', GradientType=1);
  /* IE6-9 */
}

.left-nav {
  list-style-type: none;
}

.left-nav li {
  width: 250px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 0 0 10px;
}

.left-nav li a::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  right: -1px;
  top: -5px;
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  display: block;
  border-right: 2px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
  border-bottom: 2px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
  border-left: 2px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
  border-top: 2px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
}

.left-nav li a::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  right: -1px;
  bottom: -5px;
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  display: block;
  border-right: 2px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
  border-top: 2px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
  border-left: 2px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
  border-bottom: 2px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
}

.left-nav li a {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #030406;
  /* Permalink - use to edit and share this gradient: http://colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/#373f49+0,080b0f+50,222f3e+100 */
  background: #373f49;
  /* Old browsers */
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, #373f49 0%, #080b0f 50%, #222f3e 100%);
  /* FF3.6-15 */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #373f49 0%, #080b0f 50%, #222f3e 100%);
  /* Chrome10-25,Safari5.1-6 */
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #373f49 0%, #080b0f 50%, #222f3e 100%);
  /* W3C, IE10+, FF16+, Chrome26+, Opera12+, Safari7+ */
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#373f49', endColorstr='#222f3e', GradientType=1);
  /* IE6-9 */
  line-height: 50px;
  color: #90a1b6;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, 'sans-serif';
  border-top-left-radius: 5px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 0px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 1), 0 6px 4px -4px #1c8eff, inset 0 0 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 0px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 1), 0 6px 4px -4px #1c8eff, inset 0 0 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  box-shadow: 0 1px 0px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 1), 0 6px 4px -4px #1c8eff, inset 0 0 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  border-top: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
  border-right: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
}

.left-nav li a:hover {
  color: #FFF;
  background-color: #000D51;
  /* Permalink - use to edit and share this gradient: http://colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/#1e87f3+0,051e68+27,000245+27,0269ca+100 */
  background: #1e87f3;
  /* Old browsers */
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, #1e87f3 0%, #051e68 27%, #000245 27%, #0269ca 100%);
  /* FF3.6-15 */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #1e87f3 0%, #051e68 27%, #000245 27%, #0269ca 100%);
  /* Chrome10-25,Safari5.1-6 */
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #1e87f3 0%, #051e68 27%, #000245 27%, #0269ca 100%);
  /* W3C, IE10+, FF16+, Chrome26+, Opera12+, Safari7+ */
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#1e87f3', endColorstr='#0269ca', GradientType=1);
  /* IE6-9 */
}

.left-nav li a:hover::before {
  border-right: 2px solid rgba(26, 119, 207, 1);
  border-bottom: 2px solid rgba(26, 119, 207, 1);
  border-left: 2px solid rgba(26, 119, 207, 0);
  border-top: 2px solid rgba(26, 119, 207, 0);
}

.left-nav li a:hover::after {
  border-right: 2px solid rgba(26, 119, 207, 1);
  border-top: 2px solid rgba(26, 119, 207, 1);
  border-left: 2px solid rgba(26, 119, 207, 0);
  border-bottom: 2px solid rgba(26, 119, 207, 0);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <ul class="left-nav">
    <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="">About Us</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Services</a></li>
    <li><a href="">FAQs</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Contact Us</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: much close, please see the right border a bit different from left side radius

Comment: @KashifLatif updated, this is probably as close as it's gonna get without use of images.

Comment: only one thing the black color is also in 3 shades just like blue

Comment: @KashifLatif I thought at this point you could've added it yourself. ;) Technically, there's also a pattern.

Comment: :D you got me here :)

Comment: Nice solution +1

Comment: @KashifLatif I think my answer matches closer to the image you provided than your suggested edits. I think it should stay as is.

Comment: @KashifLatif yeah, but it's not present in the image in your question.

Comment: @SergChernata it is ok if you don't want my edit :) but that was right according to my question image

Answer (score 1):

I've build this using the code from Serg Chernata.. Thanks a lot Serg, i love http://colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/ :D

@Kashif Latif: this should be a little closer.. :)

```css
.container {
  width: 350px;
  border: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
  background: #0d0e0f;
}

.left-nav {
  list-style-type: none;
}

.left-nav li {
  width: 250px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 0 0 10px;
}

.left-nav li a::before{
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  right: -1px;
  top: -5px;
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  display:block;
  border-right: 2px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.3);
  border-bottom: 2px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.3);
  border-left: 2px solid rgba(255,255,255,0);
  border-top: 2px solid rgba(255,255,255,0);
}

.left-nav li a::after{
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  right: -1px;
  bottom: -5px;
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  display:block;
  border-right: 2px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.3);
  border-top: 2px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.3);
  border-left: 2px solid rgba(255,255,255,0);
  border-bottom: 2px solid rgba(255,255,255,0);
}

.left-nav li a {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #030406;
  /* Permalink - use to edit and share this gradient: http://colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/#1e87f3+0,2b2b2b+0,282828+27,141414+27,3d3d3d+100 */
  background: #595959; /* Old browsers */
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(left,  #595959 0%, #282828 27%, #141414 27%, #3d3d3d 100%); /* FF3.6-15 */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left,  #595959 0%, #282828 27%,#141414 27%,#3d3d3d 100%); /* Chrome10-25,Safari5.1-6 */
  background: linear-gradient(to right,  #595959 0%, #282828 27%,#141414 27%,#3d3d3d 100%); /* W3C, IE10+, FF16+, Chrome26+, Opera12+, Safari7+ */
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#1e87f3', endColorstr='#3d3d3d',GradientType=1 ); /* IE6-9 */

  line-height: 50px;
  color: #90a1b6;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, 'sans-serif';
  border-top-left-radius: 5px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 0px 0 rgba(0,0,0,1), 0 6px 4px -4px #1c8eff, inset 0 0 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 0px 0 rgba(0,0,0,1), 0 6px 4px -4px #1c8eff, inset 0 0 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  box-shadow: 0 1px 0px 0 rgba(0,0,0,1), 0 6px 4px -4px #1c8eff, inset 0 0 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  border-top: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
  border-right: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
}

.left-nav li a:hover {
  color: #FFF;
  background-color: #000D51;
  /* Permalink - use to edit and share this gradient: http://colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/#1e87f3+0,051e68+27,000245+27,0269ca+100 */
  background: #1e87f3;
  /* Old browsers */
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, #1e87f3 0%, #051e68 27%, #000245 27%, #0269ca 100%);
  /* FF3.6-15 */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #1e87f3 0%, #051e68 27%, #000245 27%, #0269ca 100%);
  /* Chrome10-25,Safari5.1-6 */
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #1e87f3 0%, #051e68 27%, #000245 27%, #0269ca 100%);
  /* W3C, IE10+, FF16+, Chrome26+, Opera12+, Safari7+ */
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#1e87f3', endColorstr='#0269ca', GradientType=1);
  /* IE6-9 */
}

.left-nav li a:hover::before{
  border-right: 2px solid rgba(26,119,207,1);
  border-bottom: 2px solid rgba(26,119,207,1);
  border-left: 2px solid rgba(26,119,207,0);
  border-top: 2px solid rgba(26,119,207,0);
}

.left-nav li a:hover::after{
  border-right: 2px solid rgba(26,119,207,1);
  border-top: 2px solid rgba(26,119,207,1);
  border-left: 2px solid rgba(26,119,207,0);
  border-bottom: 2px solid rgba(26,119,207,0);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <ul class="left-nav">
    <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="">About Us</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Services</a></li>
    <li><a href="">FAQs</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Contact Us</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: 95% perfect i'm updating it :)

Answer (score 0):

I have used the CSS Linear-greadient Effect.
Look at: [W3Schools Link](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_gradients.asp)

Here is a link to what I have made so far: 
https://jsfiddle.net/ev1gjqL1/

```
background-image:
linear-gradient(
  to right, 
  #197be2,
  #091458,
  #091458,
  #197be2
);
```

Comment: nice effort but need more to stay close